# how to search through a mongodb collection for dictionary keys nested in array

Tags: python, mongodb

i have some data in a mongodb database collection  (i know which collection so im only looking through the collection ) with documents that looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52a93577dadf672b96062729"), 
  "owner" : "user1", 
  "files" : [  
              {  "IyzkmGh4YGD61Tc3TJjaEY17hDldH" : "rws" } 
            ] 
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52a92f43dadf672b96062725"), 
  "owner" : "user2", 
  "files" : [    
              {       "tUI7RtvpHZklptvHVYssamlgHP6xs" : "rws" },
              {       "RsxRDQdXmHgmSLhMJ8tPxILxarruK" : "rws" },    
              {       "IyzkmGh4YGD61Tc3TJjaEY17hDldH" : "rw" },      
              {       "YA4to7HaB5Gm6JuZrwYrFit7IzvgO" : "rws" } 
           ] 
}
```

im trying to think of a way to find all documents  that have a particular dictionary key  in the array of files  within them

like for the sample data if i search using the string `IyzkmGh4YGD61Tc3TJjaEY17hDldH`, id like both samples to match since they both have a dictionary with that key in their list of files, how would i perform this query? im working with the python motor to access mongodb. The reason is i'd like to delete these entries when files they represent are no longer in existence, 
The schema is at my disposal, i could change it to make this kind of search more sane,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use dot notation in your query keys to do this, using the `$exists` operator to just check for existence:

```
db.test.find({'files.IyzkmGh4YGD61Tc3TJjaEY17hDldH': {'$exists': 1}})
```

To find all docs that contain those files and remove them:

```
db.test.update(
    {'files.IyzkmGh4YGD61Tc3TJjaEY17hDldH': {'$exists': 1}},
    {'$pull': {'files': {'IyzkmGh4YGD61Tc3TJjaEY17hDldH': {'$exists': 1}}}},
    multi=True)
```

Comment: any idea how i would delete the entry(s)? i tried different variants of this and it did not work:   
db.user_data.update({'projects.IyzkmGh4YGD61Tc3TJjaEY17hDldH': {'$exists': 1}},{ $pull : { 'projects' : 'IyzkmGh4YGD61Tc3TJjaEY17hDldH' }})

Comment: awesome, it worked,  i had no idea i could refer to the value of the document i just found with {'$exists':1}, mongodb is pretty cool. where is this use case explained, i could not find this  in here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/
you certainly understand mongodb

Comment: @mike You're not referring to the value of the doc you just found with `$exists`, you're simply using it to identify the elements to `$pull` from `files`, in the same way you used it to identify the documents to update.