# Find dictionary keys in mongodb with dot infront of their key values

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have some data in a mongodb database collection that looks like this

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "63737b4b654d9b6a0c3a2006"
    },
    "tag": {
        "tagName": 0.10534846782684326
    }
}
```

and I want to check if a dictionary with a specific `tagName` exists. To do so, we can apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662691/how-to-search-through-a-mongodb-collection-for-dictionary-keys-nested-in-array)

```
mycollection.find({f"tag.{'tagName'}": {"$exists": True}})
```

However, some `tagNames` have a dot `.` in front, e.g.,

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "63737b4b654d9b6a0c3a2006"
    },
    "tag": {
        ".tagName": 0.10534846782684326
    }
}
```

So when I run the query

```
mycollection.find({f"tag.{'.tagName'}": {"$exists": True}})
```

returns that the dictionary whose key name is `.tagName` is not found. This is because of the double dot in `f"tag.{'.tagName'}"`. Can we write the query in such a way in order to avoid this situation?

**Mongodb version:**

```
db version v4.4.13
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.13",
    "gitVersion": "df25c71b8674a78e17468f48bcda5285decb9246",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu2004",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first syntax looks a little odd to me. I don't think it should have the curly brackets. You can see in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ppBvTJxFIx-) that it doesn't find the first document. So you may be looking to remove the curly brackets from the query in both situations, and [here is an example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hz1E9d3It8a) where doing so correctly returns the first document.

Now regarding the `.` character in the name, one approach would be to use [the `$getField` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/). That operator helps retrieve field names that are otherwise ambiguous or contain special characters. An example (that would only retrieve the second document) might look like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $ifNull: [
      {
        $getField: {
          field: ".tagName",
          input: "$tag"
        }
      },
      false
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/52aNzvjcI_N)

You may combine the two conditions with a `$or` to return both documents, [playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0OrUZDlR251).

I would recommend updating your data to remove the extra `.` character. Its presence is going to make working with the data more difficult and probably cause some performance issues since many of the operations won't be able to effectively use indexes.

---

##### Version 4.4 and earlier

As noted in the comments, the `$getField` operator is new in version `5.0`. To accomplish something similar prior to that you could use the `$objectToArray` operator.

Effectively what you will do here is convert `$tag` to an array of `k`, `v` pairs where `k` contains the field name. You can then filter directly against that name (`k`) looking for the value(s) of interest.

The verbose, but arguably more readable, approach to doing so looks like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_92WcmGjaqb):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tagNames": {
        "$objectToArray": "$tag"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "tagNames.k": {
        $in: [
          "tagName",
          ".tagName"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      tagNames: 0
    }
  }
])
```

You could probably collapse it down and do it directly in `find()` (via `$expr` usage), as demonstrated [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IQsPb6fZxSb). But doing so requires a little more knowledge about your schema and the structure of the `tag` field. Overall though, working with field names that contain dots is even more difficult prior to `5.0`, which further strengthens the suggestion to correct the underlying data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am dong this in python:

    cf = self.tag_collection.find({
        '$expr': {
            '$ifNull': [
                {
                    '$getField': {
                        'field': text,
                        'input': "$tag"
                    }
                },
                False
            ]
        }
    })

where `text` is '.tagName' and when I am writing `list(cf)` I am getting:

Comment: {OperationFailure}Unrecognized expression '$getField', full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "Unrecognized expression '$getField'", 'code': 168, 'codeName': 'InvalidPipelineOperator' 

The reason I am doing it to transform the cursor in to a list so as to see the result. Any ideas of what is wrong please?

Comment: What version? The `$getField` operator is new in `5.0`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am having 4.4.13. Is there an alternative solution for this version?

Comment: Edited to add an approach for that version (definitely helps to include that in your question originally). Probably best to use that as a starting point to correct the field name in the data, otherwise you'll be constantly dealing with this problem every time you want to interact with the data.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I will try to follow your suggestion of correcting the fields. Before closing the post I am trying to verify some queries in python with


a=self.tag_collection.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "tagNames": {
                "$objectToArray": "$tag"
            }
        }
    },
    {"$match": {
        "tagNames.k": {
            "$in": [
                "'.tagName"
            ]
        }
    }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "tagNames": 0
        }
    }
])

Comment: The only difference with the code in your post is that some attributes are strings now. Doing that, `list(a)` is an empty list. Could you please take a look? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think that it's going to be effective to try and solve a different problem in the comments, consider opening a new question. Why do you have both `"` _and_ `'` characters around `.tagName` in your `$match` statement? What attributes are strings and where are they strings at? The `aggregate` itself is not going to change any of the data in the collection itself, nor should the temporary field we are adding (`tagNames`) even be visible in the output since we are removing it in the final `$project`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, `'` shouldn;t be in my comment.